# Way to retrieve access and refresh tokens from Token Store in Spring Security Oauth2

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

Is there a way to retrieve access and refresh tokens from TokenStore in Spring Security Oauth2 if you are using in memory storage of the tokens?

Is there any endpoint that makes this easier, or is there any other workaround?

From what I analyzed, TokenEndpoint doesn't provide any endpoint besides **/oauth/token**: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/endpoint/TokenEndpoint.html

Comment: spring-security-oauth2 only provides this endpoint to get the token

Answer (score 2):

If you define the TokenStore as a Bean in your configuration then you can inject it in your own controller:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthServerOAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
    //...
    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
       return new InMemoryTokenStore();
    }
}
```

Within the controller you can provide a handler that reads the tokens and returns them:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/tokens")
public class TokensEndpoint {
  @Autowired
  TokenStore tokenStore;

  @GetMapping
  public ResponseEntity<List<String>> allTokens(@RequestParam String clientId) {
    Collection<OAuth2AccessToken> tokens = tokenStore.findTokensByClientId(clientId);
    List<String> tokenValues = tokens.stream().map(OAuth2AccessToken::getValue).collect(Collectors.toList());
    return ResponseEntity.ok(tokenValues);
  }
}
```

**You should take care that the endpoint itself is properly secured.**

Then you can retrieve the access tokens like this:

```
curl -X GET 'http://localhost:8080/api/tokens?clientId=sampleClientId'
```

If you also want to include the refresh tokens you just need to extend the mapping in the handler method.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, I wanted to retrieve the tokens from an already running application, without recompiling and starting again the service.

That's one thing. Another thing is that I am pretty sure that JwtTokenStore doesn't store anything in memory, since it doesn't have any ApprovalStore defined.

More here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/token/store/JwtTokenStore.html

Comment: Thank you for the answer though :)